Android Bundle 'getSerializable(String?): Serializable?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

/**
 * Returns the value associated with the given key, or {@code null} if:
 * <ul>
 *     <li>No mapping of the desired type exists for the given key.
 *     <li>A {@code null} value is explicitly associated with the key.
 *     <li>The object is not of type {@code clazz}.
 * </ul>
 *
 * @param key   a String, or null
 * @param clazz The expected class of the returned type
 * @return a Serializable value, or null
 */
@Nullable
public <T extends Serializable> T getSerializable(@Nullable String key,
        @NonNull Class<T> clazz) {
    return super.getSerializable(key, requireNonNull(clazz));
}

"My question is how to use Bundle's getSerializable method to retrieve collection objects."

Serializable is considered a bad idea at all, due to security issues.  See https://www.infoworld.com/article/3275924/oracle-plans-to-dump-risky-java-serialization.html

It's preferable to use Parcelable for Android rather than Serializable.
Hence, if you implement Parcelable for your TreeCatalogue class (easiest way is to use Parcelize)
Then you can use:
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", treeCatalogue)

When you create the bundle and:
val treeCatalogue = bundle.getParcelableArrayList<TreeCatalogue>("data")

When you restore it.
You can also use BundleCompat to get rid of the deprecation warning:
val treeCatalogue = BundleCompat.getParcelableArrayList(bundle, "data", TreeCatalogue::class.java)


Why are you suggesting ignoring the deprecation warning when the BundleCompat class has methods specifically to avoid those deprecation warnings?

@ianhanniballake Probably because the last time I actually used bundles that didn't exist, will edit, thanks :)

 override fun restoreBundle(bundle: Bundle) {
        //  val treeCatalogueArrayList = bundle.getSerializable("data") as ArrayList<TreeCatalogue>?
        val treeCatalogueArrayList = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            bundle.getParcelableArrayList("data", TreeCatalogue::class.java)
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            bundle.getParcelableArrayList("data")
        }
        if (treeCatalogueArrayList != null) {
            currentTreeCatalogueList = treeCatalogueArrayList
        }
        isRestore = true
    }

    override fun saveBundle(bundle: Bundle) {
        //   bundle.putSerializable("data", currentTreeCatalogueList)
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", currentTreeCatalogueList)
    }

That's what I'm doing at the moment
